# DataBinding Error and Changing only an elements DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a view that has a view model. This all works great. However, I want to change the data context of only a button to code behind so that I can utilize a DataTrigger and bind it to a property in the code behind. Here is the button:

```
<telerik:RadButton DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Grid.Column="9" Grid.Row="4" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Click="RadCapButton_Click">
                <telerik:RadButton.Content>
                    <Image Source="/TrainLoader;component/Images/UpArrow.png"/>
                </telerik:RadButton.Content>
                <telerik:RadButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadButton">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCap}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCap}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.5"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="GhostWhite" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </telerik:RadButton.Style>
            </telerik:RadButton>
```

As you can see, I have set

`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

in the button. I think this should bind to the code behind correct?

In my DataTrigger I am trying to bind to the IsCap property as shown:

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCap}" Value="True">`

However, I am getting the DataBinding Error:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsCap' property not found on 'object' ''RadButton' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=IsCap; DataItem='RadButton' (Name=''); target element is 'RadButton' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. The problem arose when I set `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`. This caused the Button to bind to itself. Instead of using the previous line of code I had to use `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. This caused the datacontext to be set to the usercontrol that the button was contained in. This solved my issue.